# SEDE query returns no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataexplorer, data.stackexchange.com

I have the following query on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 2 
  AND CreationDate > '2022-05-06'
  AND CommentCount = 3
  AND Tags LIKE '%php%'
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

I am trying to get answers that were posted today in the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag that also have 3 comments.

But all I receive is:

> 0 rows returned in 51274 ms

Comment: The link tells : "Page Not Found"

Comment: So, there are no records that match you filter criteria. Try commenting out everything in the WHERE clause, running the query and then adding back each filter criteria 1 by 1 until you see which one is filtering out all your records

Comment: The data explorer isn’t real-time

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that SE Data Explorer is not always up to date, but the problem seems to be elsewhere.
The column `Tags` is `null` for answers.
If you want to get the tags you must query the question which you can get by the column `ParentId`.

Use a self join:

```
SELECT TOP 10 p1.* 
FROM Posts p1 INNER JOIN Posts p2
ON p2.Id = p1.ParentId
WHERE p1.PostTypeId = 2 
  AND p2.Tags LIKE '%php%' 
  AND p1.CommentCount = 3
  -- AND <your date condition here>
ORDER BY p1.CreationDate DESC
```

See the [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1588560).

Comment: This is also true. Well, [almost](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1588561/1940647/).

Answer (score 0):

First, your query seems *extremely* selective. Give me all the answers to PHP questions from today where the answer has *exactly* 3 comments? I don't know that you're ever going to find a whole lot of those. Maybe if you change your criteria to `CommentCount >= 3` (and go after tags the right way), but even with those fixes, comments on *answers* don't often get that high (or stay around very long).

Second, SEDE is updated *weekly,* on Sundays. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369174/the-sede-refresh-job-didnt-start) (which links to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackapps/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc), which you can use to monitor status), and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366190/sede-refresh-didnt-happen-this-sunday). (It happened to be that just [this weekend, the normal refresh failed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378580/165455), but that wouldn't have contributed to this specific issue.)

The SEDE refresh is an extensive operation because the data is transformed in various ways (the structure is simplified to make your queries easier, and the data is sanitized to remove any PII). So on a Saturday, no, you're not going to find any posts there from today (well, after the prior Sunday).

You can just check [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1588550/1940626/how-fresh-is-sede) to see why your `WHERE` clause is additionally too selective:

```
SELECT MAX(CreationDate) FROM Posts;
```

Once you've picked *date* criteria that work, you can fix the other issues in the query.